# trying to know more about verilog language, vhdl,and assembly language

Tags: system-verilog

I would like to know what is the difference between verilog and assembly language.

Next semester we will be working with micro-controllers, but I would like to learn a little bit about it before the semester begins. I've been doing a lot of research about low-level programming, and so far I have gained a good understanding in assembly language, but I get confused trying to understand Verilog and VHDL?

Comment: You do realize assembly and verilog/vhdl have as much in common as setting a train schedule and laying the tracks. Be more specific about your question. Tell us what confuses you, what you have tried, and fix the tags. SystemVerilog not relevant to this question. Try assembly verilog vhdl microcontroller. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

Verilog and VHDL are completely different languages for describing hardware, for purposes of programming FPGAs.

FPGAs are devices that can be on-the-fly programmed to implement any sort of digital logic (and sometimes analog too).

So using verilog or VHDL, I can design a circuit that creates a couple latches, some twos-complement adders, a mux, and a clock source, and suddenly you've just designed a circuit that can calculate. You could then take the output from the VHDL compiler (or whatever its called), "download" it to the FPGA, and now you actually have some hardware that can be used to do calculation.

Of course, you can use FPGAs to implement all sorts of complicated stuff - even a full custom CPU. One uses verilog and VHDL to design the circuits that are programmed to FPGAs. Those circuits could implement something simple like a ripple counter, or something more complex like a LCD driver, or something even more complex like a USB transceiver. You can go from as simple as a few latches to as complicated as a fully operating CPU; as long as its digital hardware, you can make whatever you want with VHDL and some FPGAs.

To clarify further -

"Assembly language" typically refers to raw instructions given to some sort of CPU. Of course, there are many different types of CPUs (x86, ARM, SPARC, MIPS) and further many different variants of those types of CPUs. Each CPU has its own instruction set.

Machine code is complete, fully specified, ready to be executed instructions. Assembly languages allow you type instructions from your CPU's instruction set in plain text, use labels and such, and describe the memory layout structure of the program. Put the assembly through an assembler and out comes machine code in your CPUs machine instruction set.

You could design your own CPU from scratch using VHDL. As you're designing the CPU, you would have it implement your own custom instruction set. From there, you could take the VHDL for your CPU, compile it, write it to an FPGA and have your own custom CPU. Then you could start writing programs for your made-up CPU using your custom instruction set by writing a custom assembler. Some friends of mine in college did this for giggles.

For example, you know how most CPUs are load-store, register based CPUs? Instructions tend to go something like this:

- Load the value '1' into register A
- Load the value '2' into register B
- Add register A and register B, storing result in register A

(You just added 1 + 2! Heh)

That sort of model of computation happens to be the most popular, but it's not the only way you could do computation. What if you had a stack based CPU, where you push values onto a hardware stack, and then computations work with the values on the top of the stack, pushing results back onto the stack.

For instance:

- Push 1 onto the stack (stack current contains: 1)
- Push 2 onto the stack (stack current contains: 2 1)
- Push 3 onto the stack (stack currently contains: 3 2 1 )
- Add

  - 'Add' takes the top two elements on the stack, adds them together, and pushes the result on the top of the stack.
  - Stack now contains: 5 1
- Add

  - Stack now contains: 6

Neat isn't it? As far as a computation model goes, it has its advantages - operands tend to be short, and need fewer bits. Smaller instructions means that the CPU can be faster.

The problem is that no such processor like this exists anymore.

But if you knew what you were doing, you could design one in VHDL, program it to an FGPA, and suddenly you have one of the only operating stack-based processors in existence.

Say, if you were doing a masters thesis, for instance, you might dig around and find out that virtual-machine-based programming languages like C# and Java compile down to a bytecode for a CPU that doesn't really exist, but the model for that CPU proves useful for making code portable. You might find out that the imaginary machines used by these languages are based on stack-based processor models. If you were looking for something interesting to do, perhaps you write in VHDL a processor that natively implements the Java bytecode language. Now you'd be the only person that has a computer that can directly run Java.

Answer (score 2):

[Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog) and [VHDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl) are both [HDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_description_language)s (Hardware description languages) used mainly for describing digital electronics. Their targets may be [FPGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fpga) or [ASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) (custom silicon).

[Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) level on the other hand is using an processors [instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set) to perform a series of calculations. Every thing executed on a computer eventually ends up as an assembly level instruction. One example of an instruction set would be the [x86 ISA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language).

Summary: [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog), [VHDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl) describe hardware. [Assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language) is the low level program being executed on a processor.